# Pandas: idiomatic way to perform multiple complex aggregations?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have a table as follows:

```
ID   SCORE
A    NaN
A    NaN
B    1
B    2
C    5
```

I want the following output:

```
ID    SUM_SCORE   SIZE_SCORE
A     NaN         2
B     3           2
C     5           1
```

Since I want to preserve NaN's, I need to use `sum(min_count=1)`.  So I have the following thus far:

```
grp = df.groupby('ID')
sum_score = grp['SCORE'].sum(min_count=1).reset_index()
size_score = grp['SCORE'].size().reset_index()
result = pd.merge(sum_score, size_score, on=['ID'])
```

This feels really inelegant.  Is there a better way to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s=df.groupby('ID').SCORE.agg([('sum_score',lambda x : x.sum(min_count=1)),
                             ('size_score','size')] ).reset_index()
  ID  sum_score  size_score
0  A        NaN           2
1  B        3.0           2
2  C        5.0           1
```

Comment: What does IIUC mean?

Comment: just curious, this takes ~7s on my data set.  Computing them separately takes 0.046 seconds.   any idea why?

Comment: @AlexanderDavid I am not sure about it , if you would like speed it up do it separate then join back

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate using the following:

```
df_agg = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).agg(["sum","count"])

# rename your columns
df_agg.columns = ["ID","SUM_SCORE", "SIZE_SCORE"]
```

Comment: this will not retain NaN's since `sum([NaN, NaN])` in pandas is 0 by default see here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15674

Comment: Ah, got it. That's interesting. And ^above answer looks good.